# Sliding with the finger between activities

Tags: android

I have an app with quiet a lot of Activities. I go from one to another throught an arrow in the Toolbar with an Intent. However, I would like to give the app a more intuitive form using the finger to move between them. I have read: https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/android-ejemplo-de-viewpager-en-android-parte-1/ but it hasn't  given me any solution to my problem. Which other link or article should I read?

Comment: [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info) has very good tutorials and I believe it has one for ViewPager as well. You need to use fragments along with ViewPager to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you have to use fragments instead of activities in order to slide by moving next screen using view pager. Follow [that example](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

and hopefully you will get it what you want.

Comment: Thank you, both, I'll try to put it into practice.

Answer (score 0):

The Article You have Link to is the perfect article. You can use finger to move between the activities using ViewPager by swiping left right. If you want to know how View Pager works with Fragments then this is a great video tutorial :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9phSvgqpNtE

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    ViewPager mPager;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_frame_container);
    mPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    }
}

 class ViewPagerAdapterextends FragmentPagerAdapter {

     public CaptionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
         super(fragmentManager);
     }

     @Override
     public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
     Fragment fragment = null;
     if (position == 0){
        fragment = FragmentA.getInstance();
        }
     else if (position == 1){
        fragment = FragmentB.getInstance();
        }
     return fragment;
     }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
         return 2;
     }
}
```

This Exmaples is using Fragments. I hope this helps